# Listing details in one table based on count in another table

Tags: mysql, sql

Given three tables

- departments
- dept_emp
- employees

I want to list employees who are assigned to departments with more than 50,000 employees.

I've tried several different approaches using sub-queries but haven't got it right.

Here is one failed attempt. Note: I want the *details* for the employee and the department they are in

```
select 
    a.dept_name,
    c.*
from
    departments a
left outer join
    dept_emp b
on
    b.dept_no = a.dept_no
left outer join
    employees c
on
    c.emp_no = b.emp_no
where
    c.emp_no
in
    (select
        emp_no
    from
        dept_emp
    group by
        dept_no
    having
        count(dept_no) > 50000
    )
```

Comment: please post your attempts too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
select 
a.dept_name,
c.*
from departments a
inner join dept_emp b on b.dept_no = a.dept_no
inner join employees c on c.emp_no = b.emp_no
where b.dept_no in
(select dept_no
from dept_emp
group by dept_no
having count(*) > 50000
)
```

Comment: Why does the inner join work and the outer not?

Comment: that is not the problem. you were `group`ing by `emp_no` instead of `dept_no` in the sub-query.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have a more difficult one I'm working on but this may guide me.